# vscode does not want to launch

Tags: snap, visual-studio-code

I tried to launch VScode but it failed. i tried to launch it from terminal running `code` and the output was this

```
$ code
/snap/code/52/electron-launch: line 28: /snap/code/52/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders: No such file or directory
/snap/code/52/usr/share/code/bin/code: 53: /snap/code/52/usr/share/code/bin/code: /snap/code/52/usr/share/code/bin/../code: not found
```

likewise, i tried to remove it using `sudo snap remove code` and reinstalling it using `sudo snap install code --classic` & also tried to use GUI Snapstore but all failed to solve the issue.

This issue occurred after i made an update that corrupted a visual thing due to nvidia and i rolled back using Timeshift and reupdated the system and the entire system is working perfect except for VScode.

I also tried to remove VScode files from `/snap/` & `~/snap/` but still didn't work.

hint: installing VScode does not take much time, i really doubt that it is removed or it is re-downloading the package again.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem. I solved it using apt to install VSCode.

First remove the snap files:

```
sudo snap remove --purge code
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
```

Install the necessary dependencies for adding the repository and use wget to import Microsoft’s GPG key:

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common apt-transport-https wget
wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
```

Enable the VSCode repository.

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main"
```

Install code.

```
sudo apt install code
```

Run the update/upgrade command to update your existing VSCode if that is the case.

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
```

Comment: This proved to be a good solution as when trying to debug a node app I was getting all sorts of errors re snap. Now I can debug node app. I have added a bug to github vscode. I am also hopeful it will sort out the issue I was having of getting logged off from remote desktop from vs code.